# Table of Contents causes "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis, books

I'm trying to add a table of contents to a template which I found on Sharelatex.com, but upon adding \tableofcontents, I obtain the error "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."

Anyone has a clue as to what went wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
%linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,% PDF VIEW
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,% PRINT
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{0pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\flushright
\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\\ \Huge\bfseries}[]

%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%

\begin{document}

%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%   TITLEPAGE
%
%   due to variety of titlepage schemes it is probably better to make titlepage manually
%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
\thispagestyle{empty}

{%%%
\sffamily
\centering
\Large

~\vspace{\fill}

{\huge 
Thesis title: may be long or short
}

\vspace{2.5cm}

{\LARGE
Your name
}

\vspace{3.5cm}

A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the\\
degree of Doctor of Philosophy\\[1em]
in the\\[1em]
Faculty Name\\
University Name

\vspace{3.5cm}

Supervisor: Prof. Joe Doe

\vspace{\fill}

May 2013

%%%
}%%%

\cleardoublepage
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First section}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! `\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\flushright
\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp}{0pt}{\\ \Huge\bfseries}[]` is causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code to format chapter titles has an error –  `\\` in the last mandatory argument. Furthermore it is much too complicated. With the tools provided by `titlesec`, you obtain the correct result (a small difference in the height placement of the chapter number, which can be taken care of with `\titlespacing` if necessary):

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filleft\Huge\bfseries}{\fontsize{100}{100}\selectfont\textcolor{gray75}\thechapter}{1ex}{}[]%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am able to run the code to achieve the required format now. :)

Answer (score 3):

the error means you have mis-used `\\` and in this case

```
{\\ \Huge\bfseries}[]
```

You can not *start* a title with a line break as, as the error says, there is no line to end at that point.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It works fine now :) As @Bernard has solved the main issue of having the required format (chapter number above chapter title), I will mark his as the solution to my question. Really sorry about that..

Comment: @Stoner don't worry, we both have enough points that 15 here or there will not ruin our day:-)